# Swift - cast one tuple to another

Tags: swift, tuples

How do I automatically pass one tuple as another in Swift?

Example:

```
func f(a: Int, b: Int) {
    // ...
}

let tuple1 = (a: 2, b: 3)

f(tuple1) // Works

let tuple2 = (a: 2, b: 3, c: 4)

f(tuple2) // Doesn't work

f(a: tuple2.a, b: tuple2.b) // Works
```

So what I want to do is pass `tuple2` as a `tuple1` without having to explicitly write all the parameters of `tuple1` again.

Comment: Why do you think that you could pass a tuple with more values then you defined in the function definition? It's like saying your function has one parameter that's a string, and your trying to pass it an array of strings.

Comment: I'd expect the function to take the parameters `a` and `b` and ignore `c`. Passing an array instead of a string is not the same thing, in my example, I'm also passing `a` and `b`.

Comment: That's nonsense, you can't cast tuple with three elements to tuple with two elements. It's the same, as you can't cast string to int. You have to say compiler, which elements of tuple, you want to add to new tuple.

Comment: Have you ever heard of duck typing?